# How to collect log in memory until exception occured and write to file after?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, nlog

I'm using NLog. And I wanna do next: keep everything logged in memory until something bad will happens. If the request is completed successfully - flush memory log. If some exception has occurred - write to log file everything collected from the very beginning of the request.
What should I do? Create two loggers (MemoryLogger and FileLogger) and use the first one during a request to gather info and if necessary use second to write all info per request to file?

And will it improve the performance or not?

Comment: 100% working code with `OutOfMemoryException`? Just use recursion.

Comment: Keeping stuff in memory until something bad happens all but guarantees that something bad will happen.

Comment: If someone unplugs your machine, your logs are gone.

Comment: Sounds similar to what this guy is trying: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/127 (Using the async-discard feature to limit the memory usage, and auto-flush to trigger the writing of the last entries on warning/error-event).

Comment: Now it seems one else is also interested in this, and have made a PR that fixes BufferingTargetWrapper to support this https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2276

Comment: Main idea is to write to log minimum info about start and finish.
But if exception has occurred - log all detailed info.

Comment: Possible solution can be found here for NLog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020718/how-to-stack-up-log-messages-and-log-them-just-when-an-exception-occurs