# How to stack up log messages and log them just when an exception occurs?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, nlog

I have a business process that executes a bunch of SQL Commands. I want to "stack up" these sql commands in a stack and write them to DB just when an exception occurs, let me explain it with some code

```
public void BusinessMethod()
{
    Log.Initialize(); // Clear the stack
    try
    {  
        Method1ThatExecutesSomeSQLs();
        Method2ThatExecutesSomeSQLs();
        Method3ThatExecutesSomeSQLs();
    }
    catch(Expection ex)
    {
        // if some exception occured in any Method above, them i write the log, otherwise, i dont want to log anything
        Log.Write();
    }
} 

//Example of some Method that executes SQL's
public void Method1ThatExecutesSomeSQLs()
{
    string sql = "select * from table";
    ExecuteSQL(sql);
    Log.StackUp("The following sql command was executed: " + sql); //Just stack up, dont write!
}
```

Does anyone know if the Log4Net or NLog supports this scenario? If not, How to implement it?

Comment: That may not help (since its not Log4Net), but instead of Log4Net I would suggest NLog, which has the feature you describe.

Comment: @Michael can you point me to the NLog page that describes this feature?

Comment: Well... I would, but I am unable to find it :( Dont remember the details, quite some time ago. But it works like this: You specifiy a level as filter condition, lets say error. If the log message is lower then the specified condition, the message will be queued. If the level is equal or higher then the specified level, the queued messages and the triggering one are getting logged. Might be a combination of buffering- and filtering targets, but i can't find examples. I am pretty sure that I did not write custom code to do this... Maybe someone else here on SO can provide an example...?

Answer (score 2):

NLog 4.5 supports the scenario out of the box. This will show the last 50 messages when a warning/error/fatal occurs (Causing the auto-flush to trigger):

```xml
<target name="consoleWarn" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Warn" >
        <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" overflowAction="Discard" bufferSize="50">
             <target xsi:type="Console" layout="${level}:${message}" />
        </target>
</target>
```

NLog 4.4 (and older) needs some more help, as BufferingWrapper doesn't have an overflowAction. Instead the AsyncWrapper can be abused:

```xml
<target name="consoleWarn" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Warn" >
        <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="500">
             <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="50" overflowAction="Discard" fullBatchSizeWriteLimit="1" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="2000000000">
                <target xsi:type="Console" layout="${level}:${message}" />
             </target>
        </target>
</target>
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/127

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue stacking up message logs in a MemoryTarget then saving it (Flushing) when needed. Look:

```
public class Program
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "Start of the process");
            // Inside Business class i have a lot of other logger.log() calls
            // Inside the business class a have a lot of DAOs that calls logger.log()
            // In ither words, all the calls to logger.log() will be stacked up
            Business b = new Business();
            b.DoSomethig();
            logger.Debug("End of the Process.");
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            var target = (MemoryTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("MemoTarget");
            var logs = target.Logs;

            // Get all the logs in the "stack" of log messages
            foreach (string s in target.Logs)
            {
                Console.Write("logged: {0}", s);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

nlog.config:

```xml
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="Memory" name="MemoTarget" layout="${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} | ${callsite} | ${message}" />
 ...
</targets>
...
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="MemoTarget" />
</rules>
....
```

After run it, the output will be:

```
logged: 30-10-2017 20:12:36 | NLog_Tests.Program.Main | Start of the process 
logged: 30-10-2017 20:12:36 | NLog_Tests.Business.DoSomethig | Some business rule was executed
logged: 30-10-2017 20:12:36 | NLog_Tests.DAOClass.ExecuteCommand | some sql was executed
logged: 30-10-2017 20:12:36 | NLog_Tests.Program.Main | End of the Process.
```

Comment: Would be nice to also add the nlog.config here :)

Comment: @Julian i added the nlog.config

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but this my (reduced) config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets async="true">
    <wrapper-target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="buffer" bufferSize="32" flushTimeout="100">
      <wrapper-target xsi:type="PostFilteringWrapper">
        <defaultFilter>level >= LogLevel.Warn</defaultFilter>
        <when exists="level >= LogLevel.Error" filter="level >= LogLevel.Trace" />
        <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" />
      </wrapper-target>
    </wrapper-target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="buffer" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

This will queue all messages (max=32) below warning level. If a message above or equal to error will be logged, the queue will be flushed.

C# Testcode with the above config. Only the warn message will be visible. If either the error or the fatal message are added all messages will be visible.

```
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(@"cfg\NLog.xml", false);
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

LOG.Trace("trace");
LOG.Debug("debug");
LOG.Info("info");
LOG.Warn("warn");
//LOG.Error("error");
//LOG.Fatal("fatal");

LogManager.Flush();
LogManager.Shutdown();
```